# Scala: Get largest number from List of tuples

Tags: list, scala, tuples

If I had a list of `(String,Double)` tuples in Scala 
        (i.e. `List[(String,Double)]`)
, how would I get the tuple with the largest `Double` value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `maxBy`:

```
val list: List[(String, Double)] = List(("a", 2.3), ("b", 3.5), ("c", 8.9))
list.maxBy(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.  The one that comes to mind is by doing a .sortBy(- _._2)

```
val t1 = ("string1", 1)
val t2 = ("string2", 5)
val t3 = ("string3", 12)
val t4 = ("string4", 3)
val t5 = ("string5", 8)

val myList = List(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

val largestTuple = myList.sortBy(- _._2).head

largestTuple: (String, Int) = (string3,12)
```

Comment: @marcospereira's answer of .maxBy is probably a better way to do it.  It essentially combines sortBy and head

Comment: No, the other answer does not do sortBy/head. There's no need to sort,and doing so is unnecessarily slow

Answer (score 1):

Also `reduce` can convey the semantics like this,

```
xs.reduce( (a,v) => if (v._2 > a._2) v else a)
```

Namely, scan the list and preserve the max value. Even so, `maxBy` is the way to go for simplicity.